# Android browser detects only portrait dimensions

Tags: javascript, android, screen, detection, android-browser

I check my browser screen resolution with the Android browser here:

http://www.screenresolution.org

http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com

And I get 768 x 1024 even in landscape mode. When I use Chrome everything is OK.

Which JavaScript code will return me the actual screen resolution in Android browser?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want a way to get the screen resolution using js?

Comment: The sites above use JS to get screen resolution, but it's not accurate for android browser when device is in landscape mode